# Can i replace the int in my Javascript with the Variable Zero when parsing a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

here is the JSON file I would like to parse

```
{
  "items": [
    0 {
      "snippet": {
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using this to parse it in Javascript:

```
var zero;
zero = 0;
isthisThingLive = data.items.zero.snippet.liveBroadCastContent;
console.log(isthisThingLive);
```

(I am not including the server code to avoid your boredom, I know it works because I use it in multiple other places)

I run into an error whenever I replace the "Zero" variable with the 0 Int. Is there a reason for this? I am relatively new to using server requests and parsing and any help would be appreciated!

The "Data" variable is used to reach the server, this is not the issue, the error I'm getting is "You can not get "Snippet" of undefined, meaning that the Zero variable is failing to be recognized but the server!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Arrays do not have keys.  They have indices.  It needs to be [0], or [zero]

Comment: That's not JSON, it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @Pointy Could you provide some clarification to : That's not JSON, the file I would like to parse is JSON

Comment: @Taplar I am confused on where the "Key" is you are pointing too?

Comment: That snippet you posted is erroneous; that "0" floating around before the first `{` is out of place, and will cause an error if you try to parse it.

Comment: `data.items.zero` <= any time you do dot notation, you are using keys to access the properties on the object.  It is the same as `data.items['zero']`.  The string 'zero' being the key. @KolemanParsley

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for this clarification! I appreciate your help and your quick answers

Comment: @KolemanParsley a handy tool for future reference is https://jsonlint.com/ - it's a validation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper json:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "snippet": {
        "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how you can access liveBroadCastContent

```
const isthisThingLive = data.items[0].snippet.liveBroadCastContent;
console.log(isthisThingLive);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Happy to help :)